# How come I can't set a $_POST value to a variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form in HTML, in which I am pulling values from with PHP. I would like to insert it into a database with SQL, but (from my experience with this issue, at least) you can't insert $_POST values with an SQL statement.

When the page is loaded on XAMPP, I get the following error of:

```
Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 26
```

My code looks something like this:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="email">
  <button class="btndef" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
?>
```

Obviously something's wrong with it, but I have no idea what!

Comment: You get that when you initially load the page or after you submit the form?

Comment: When the page is loaded @PatrickQ

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't exist because you haven't posted.  What value would you expect it to have?

Comment: `$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;`

Comment: @PatrickQ the value of the textbox when submitted

Comment: Right, and it _will_ have a value when submitted.  But you haven't submitted yet.  So it doesn't exist.

Comment: You could debug with `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: @Pevara your answer solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']){
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
?>

<form method="post" action="action-url">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="email">
  <button class="btndef" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Make sure you are doing validation while submitting the form

Comment: Yes but I want to send to phpMyAdmin, so this wouldn't work for me

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is just a User Interface for MySQL. It has nothing to do with your operation. Can you elaborate little that where you are getting the problem?? Any errors?? Please update your question.